# Simulate the print screen key in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, simulate, printscreen

i search lot in Google but i did not got anything .
can we simulate the print screen key in python ?
if yes then how to simulate the print screen key in python?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846947/get-screenshot-on-windows-with-python

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17835549/2284418

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python auto save printscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832717/python-auto-save-printscreen)

Answer (score 1):

To take a screen shot the comments you've been given will work:

[Get screenshot on Windows with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846947/get-screenshot-on-windows-with-python)
[python auto save printscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832717/python-auto-save-printscreen/17835549#17835549)

To *simulate* the print screen key you may use keystroke automation libraries, two of which I can attest work for this:

1:  [pywinauto](https://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/)

which uses [SendKeys](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SendKeys/0.3) to [simulate keystrokes](http://www.rutherfurd.net/python/sendkeys/) ([or see reference here](http://00010xg.wcomhost.com/rjp3/rjp3help/sendkeys_reference.html)).

2:  [Sikuli_cpython](https://github.com/kevlened/sikuli_cpython)

which uses the [standalone sikuli API](https://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/) to handle keystrokes and much much more. Here is then the [list of keys you can simulate](http://doc.sikuli.org/javadoc/constant-values.html) by passing the respective unicode char to the sikuli method `type()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library:

```
#pip install pyautogui
from pyautogui import press
press("printscreen")
```